# SwiftUI doesn’t detect swipe when there is an overlay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, overlay

I'm trying to create an app with an overlay that activates when there is an upwards swipe and goes away with a downward swipe. Most of the program functions normally but when I swipe with the overlay showing it can't recognize swipes in any direction. If the overlay isn't being displayed the program recognizes swipes just fine.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader{ proxy in
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere.\n \t Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere. ")
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1.0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onEnded ({ value in
                if value.translation.height < 0 {
                    isLoading = true
                }else{
                    isLoading = false
                }
                print(isLoading)
            }))
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom){
            loadingOverlay
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder private var loadingOverlay: some View{
        if(isLoading){
            SlidingView()
                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .opacity))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
        }
    }
}
struct SlidingView: View{
    
    @State private var up = false
    
    var body: some View{
        
        GeometryReader{ proxy in
            VStack(spacing: 20){
                Image(systemName: up ? "chevron.compact.up" : "chevron.compact.down")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed. Ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper. Condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere.")
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: 1000)
            .background(Color(.lightGray))
            .cornerRadius(30)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to fix:

1. Apply `.allowsHitTesting(false)` to the overlay:

```swift
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            loadingOverlay
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
```

2. Alternatively, add the drag gesture to the overlay too. You can re-use the same gesture by moving it to a computed property. While you're at it, you could avoid the warning for the deprecated animation modifier by using `withAnimation` instead:

```swift
    var dragged: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1.0, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onEnded { value in
                withAnimation {
                    isLoading = value.translation.height < 0
                }
                print(isLoading)
            }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Content as before
        }
        .gesture(dragged)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            loadingOverlay
                .gesture(dragged)
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder private var loadingOverlay: some View {
        if isLoading {
            SlidingView()
                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .opacity))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the first solution worked well for me!